# O que é o Anko?

Tags: android, kotlin

Já convertendo meus projetos Android para  o Kotlin, em algumas pesquisas que fui realizando, citaram várias vezes um tal de Anko Kotlin.

O que é esse tal de Anko? Do que se trata? Qual é seu objetivo?

Comment: Quem negativou a pergunta poderia pelo menos explicar o motivo para que eu possa edita-la e tentar colaborar mais com o SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De acordo com o [GitHub dele](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) é uma biblioteca para facilitar o desenvolvimento para Android com mecanismos para Intents, Dialogs e toasts, Logging, Resources e dimensions e ainda corotinas, uma deficiência de Kotlin.

Também conta com uma DSL para *layouts*. Exemplo:

```
verticalLayout {
    val name = editText()
    button("Say Hello") {
        onClick { toast("Hello, ${name.text}!") }
    }
}
```

Isso aí é sintaxe Kotlin. Pra que usar XML? :)

Tem um facilitador para recuperar dados do SQLite. Exemplo:

```
fun getUsers(db: ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper): List<User> = db.use {
    db.select("Users")
            .whereSimple("family_name = ?", "John")
            .doExec()
            .parseList(UserParser)
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Anko.kt).

Answer (score 7):

É uma biblioteca para Kotlin voltada especificamente ao desenvolvimento de aplicações Android, com o objetivo de deixar o código mais simples e legível, dispensando o programador de ter que se envolver com os detalhes mais profundos do SDK Android para Java.

Você encontra uma descrição mais detalhada com exemplos em:
https://www.thiengo.com.br/iniciando-com-anko-kotlin-intencoes-no-android